# open my.exe file and insert text from my.txt

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, stdout, stdin

I have a simple my.exe file with just one text-field an OK-button.
I need to open this file (via .subprocess?) and insert into text-field one line (or lines) from my.txt.
After this OK-button is automatically pushed. Any ideas on Python? Thanks!

Comment: See https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

you can use libraries like `pyautogui` or  `pynupt` to control the mouse to click on the checkbox and you can use the `locateOnScreen()` function available in pyautogui to find the coordination of the text field and the button

take care that they may take over your device XD

 Here is an insight Video That will give you details of how to Create such bots

[How to make advanced image recognition bots using python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRAIUA-Oc1Y)